# highcharts when use boost and line type left error question

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Step line types, with null values in the series'
    },
    boost : {
     seriesThreshold : 1
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, 7, null, 9],
        step: 'right',
        name: 'Right'
    }, {
        data: [5, 6, 7, 8, null, 10, 11, null, 13],
        step: 'center',
        name: 'Center'
    }, {
        data: [9, 10, 11, 12, null, 14, 15, null, 17],
        step: 'left',
        name: 'Left'
    }]

});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/boost.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

The problem is that the line type is stepping while using the boost module in the highcharts.

The first point is in error.

What can I do?

fsfiddle address
http://jsfiddle.net/fts8Lyv4/

```
series: [{
    data: [1, 2, 3, 4, null, 6, 7, null, 9],
    step: 'right',
    name: 'Right'
}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, I would suggest you report it here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues. I did a search there and could not find any bug matching what you have shown.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I will also contact highcharts